# Should you always close connections?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, concurrency

So far all the JDBC code I've seen creates and closes a connection every time. However, I'm wondering if that is necessary because my code seems to work perfectly fine and I'm reusing the same connection each time:

**Is this a bad way to do this?**

```
public static int getCount() {
    synchronized (DATABASE_ACCESS_LOCK) {
        try (ResultSet rs = QUERY.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM " + TABLE_CLIENTS)) {
            return rs.getInt(1);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should generally release your database connection *when you leave an active scope of work*.  Database connections are expensive resources.  Holding them longer than necessary makes the job of a connection pool manager that much harder.

If you are performing several DB operations together it is quite reasonable to use the same DB connection for all of those operations.  Once that group of operations is done, release the connection.

Comment: When you say expensive resources, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @paranoid-android Exactly that, they take up memory and can consume other resources, like sockets and CPU cycles.  It's a trade off, things like, the expense of creating the connection, over the expense of keeping the connection open and the amount you are using it.  There's also a drain on the database server as it needs to maintain stateful information about the connection (and all the underlying requirements such as sockets)